# Redirect traffic to different domain with same url page to blogger domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, blogger

A Month ago I moved to a custom domain in blogger, but now I want to return my old free domain of Blogspot. 
In blogger when we set custom domain its redirect the traffic to the new domain without losing traffic. example:
old.blogspot.com/anyurlpage
to:
new.com/anyurlpage

Now I want to move back to the free domain with the .blogspot.com 
new.com/anyurlpage to old.blogspot.com/anyurlpage 
How can i do the same without losing traffic? 
If I understand correctly this should do the job:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NEWDOMAIN.com [R=301,L]
```

I'll use web hosting to create a `.Htaccess` file, and paste these lines.  
Will it work?
Please help, thanks!

Comment: You cannot "fetch away" traffic from some service by writing rewrite rules into another service. If that service you currently use and you want to migrate away from does not provide any means to redirect requests, then there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Currently the custom domain are active, When I decide to return to the free domain. i will move the custom domain to web hosting and with the `.htaccess` Redirect to the blogspot domain.. is the code i mention above will do the job?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using CloudFlare for addressing this problem.

After you have setup CloudFlare on the custom domain, go to the Page Rules section of their dashboard and set a forwarding URL Page Rule with 301 redirect. To redirect all the traffic to the BlogSpot domain, use their inbuilt support for wildcards and variables. Like for example -

Detection URL - *yourcustomdomain.com/*

Redirect URL -  https://yourblogname.blogspot.com/$2

This will redirect all traffic from the custom domain to the BlogSpot URL while preserving the pathname

For more information, refer to - https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286

Comment: There is option to do it with the `.htaccess` ? i mean to change the domain only but the root after the / example: xx.com/[movethisroot] is it possible to move this /[movethisroot] to new domain without losing traffic with the `.htaccess` thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do via `.htaccess` file but that would require getting a web hosting for that purpose only. CloudFlare free plan will be enough to implement this logic and redirects would be much faster compared to the regular web hosting performance